# Is it impossible to add multiple views to a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-widget, android-scrollview

If so, it seems that either the ScrollView is rather lame (doubtful) or there's some other way to do it. Here's my code. Where it bombs (the second time through the loop, that is) is commented.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize);

    ScrollView svh = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHost);

    // Contacts data snippet adapted from
    // http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // Create a Linear Layout for each contact?
            LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
            llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llp.weight = 1.0f;

            CheckBox cbOnDemand = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbOnDemand.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbOnDemand);

            CheckBox cbTime = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbTime.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbTime);

            CheckBox cbSpace = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
            cbSpace.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbSpace);

            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setTag(id);
            tv.setText(name);
            tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(tv);

            svh.addView(llay); // it transports me to Eclipse's Debug perspective when I hit this line the SECOND time around.
            // One cat on stackOverflow said to do this, another said it
            // would be unnecessary
            svh.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two things you can do to solve this.

1) Make the only child of the `ScrollView` be a vertical `LinearLayout` and add all of your children to the `LinearLayout` instead of the `ScrollView`.

2) A preferable alternative would be to use a `ListView` (which is probably implemented using a `LinearLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll go with option A, as the problem with option 2 (which was my first stab at this) is that I couldn't figure out a way to be able to programmatically identify each checkbox at runtime - how to know which checkbox on which row is being clicked. I need the checkboxes to have a Tag value corresponding to the Contact id so I know which options are being selected for each Contact. That's why I went the dynamically-create-the-widgets route, so I can add that tag in the loop that creates the checkbox (and textView) widgets.

Answer (score 7):

Only one view can be included in a `ScrollView`. However, that view could be a layout, like a `LinearLayout`. Typically what I do is add such a view to a `ScrollView`, and it works great.

Example:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just in case he is still confused. The LinearLayout is put directly inside the ScrollView. It is used just to wrapper all the stuff you want to put in there.

Comment: I think I am putting the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView; I guess I need to subsequently create LinearLayouts that contain the three checkboxes and the textView and add them to the outermost LinearLayout, not to the ScrollView.

Comment: 9 years later and this still holds true 

Answer (score 1):

Nested Scroll view hold only  one direct view as child  if you wants to add more then you have to include just one view child as view group like linear layout,that it can hold more views,as you can add buttons etc.. in other words so view group can hold multiple views if you put them as child view of  NestedScrollView. i include a layout as child of NestedScrollView and its further have many views.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/descriptioncontent_layout" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

add multiple items to description content_layout ...etc.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <include layout="@layout/descption_layout" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <include layout="@layout/howtodoit" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Description_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Full Body:"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/how"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="If you are brand new to yoga, there are certain postures that are essential for you to learn so you can feel comfortable in a class or practicing on your own at home"
    android:id="@+id/detaildescription"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```